# ERROR 1366: 1366: Incorrect string value

Tags: mysql

I get an error when trying to insert characters like čćšđž:

```
ERROR 1366: 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x87'
```

I've searched the internet and found out that this error may be caused if I try to insert character which needs more than 3 bytes, but as you can see in this error, my character takes only 2 bytes.
Collation is set to `utf8_unicode_ci`, mysql version is 5.6.27.
Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Since `\xC4\x87` seems to be the correct UTF-8 representation for U+0107 you are either not telling MySQL what encoding to use when you stablish the connection or you're reporting a wrong one.

Comment: I'm using Laravel so I guess that's already setup in background

Comment: Unless you already knows what's wrong, you have nothing to lose if you verify it anyway.

Comment: I have it set, and still have this error. In my case Symfony/Doctrine which is incorrectly inputting binary data in the DB